# Do I need to use both chown nobody:users and chmod 755

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

In the command line `chown nobody:users /mnt/user/A && chmod 755 /mnt/user/A` can I use only `chmod 755 /mnt/user/A` to give access to anyone or do I need both to make it fully accessible for everyone?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are encountering?  This should not be necessary

Comment: The question is wrong by itself; please explain what you want to achieve. If /mnt/user/A is a windows filesystem: no. Neither will work. If it is a samba share: no. If it is a ext share it is the wrong approach "nobody" is NOT a linux user but a user used  by external tools (from windows often) because from that end the user is often unknown. And NO it is also not the correct approach. YOU need to be the user, others is the THIRD number in chmod

Answer (score 1):

From whatever little understanding I have, `chmod 755` means owner will have read, write and execute permission while  those part of the same group and other users will have read and execute permission. if this serves your purpose then `chmod 755 file` is enough.